# Getting error while forming Dynamic PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to form below SQL statement.  but getting this weird error which I can't seem to figure out. I have executed each statement individually outside the loop and they are working fine. Please someone help me finding the error.

**Error**

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 14:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

**PLSQL Statement:**

```
 DECLARE
 L_sql VARCHAR2(2000):=NULL;
BEGIN      
FOR val IN (SELECT generation_qtr from test_1) 
  LOOP
      L_sql:=L_sql ||' MAX(DECODE(generation_qtr, '||''''||val||''''||' cum_actual_gen)) AS ' || val ||','||chr(10);
  END LOOP;
  L_sql:='SELECT assetname, '|| L_sql;
  L_sql:=substr(L_sql,1,LENGTH(L_sql)-1);
dbms_output.put_line(L_sql);
END;
```

**Oracle Version -11.2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're referring to `val` directly, but that's a cursor row type. You need to specify the column name, even if there is only one:

```
... ||val.generation_qtr|| ...
```

... in both places you use it in the concatenation. So it woudl become:

```
      L_sql:=L_sql ||' MAX(DECODE(generation_qtr, '||''''
        || val.generation_qtr ||''''||' cum_actual_gen)) AS '
        || val.generation_qtr ||','||chr(10);
```

If you're going to execute this dynamically then the new line characters aren't going to be very useful, but I guess they help for debugging.